# Why does my Java program select multiple checkboxes at once inside a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, jcheckbox

I have an issue when adding checkboxes to a Jtable, or more specifically when selecting a checkbox. I am able to select individual checkboxes, but when I do it automatically selects the other present checkboxes.

ex: First is chosen, then all of the proceeding checkboxes are selected.
Or second is chosen, then all of the proceeding are chosen.
If last is chosen, all checkboxes above are selected. 
If I repeatedly click and unclick checkboxes I can finally choose them individually.

The checkboxes are present in the first column of the table, with each row having a single checkbox.

I've been trying to figure this out for a day now, and I can't come to any conclusions; so some help would be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

**Source for creating the JTable:**

```
  protected void createTable() {

    JobPlanDataTable dataModel = new JobPlanDataTable();
    dataModel.setTimeOffset( 0 );


    this.ordersTable.setHighlighters(HighlighterFactory.createAlternateStriping());
    this.ordersTable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
    this.ordersTable.setModel( dataModel );
    this.ordersTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    this.ordersTable.setTransferHandler(new TableRowTransferHandler(this.ordersTable)); 

    for( int i = 0; i < dataModel.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
        if( i== 0 ) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = new CheckCellRenderer(); 
            ca.cygnusconsulting.utilities.ColumnData col = dataModel.getColumn( i );
            JCheckBox tableCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            tableCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JCheckBox.CENTER);
            tableCheckBox.setBackground(this.ordersTable.getBackground());
            TableCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(tableCheckBox);
            TableColumnExt column = new TableColumnExt( i, col.getWidth(), renderer, editor );
            //TableModelListener listener = new TableModelListener();
            column.setMaxWidth(col.getMaxWidth());
            this.ordersTable.addColumn( column );   

            // add action listener on check box
            tableCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
                    tableCheckBoxActionPerformed(e);
            }
            });
        }
        else{
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new FormatTableCellRenderer();
        ca.cygnusconsulting.utilities.ColumnData col = dataModel.getColumn( i );
        renderer.setHorizontalAlignment( col.getAlignment() );
        TableColumnExt column = new TableColumnExt( i, col.getWidth(), renderer, null );
        this.ordersTable.addColumn( column );
        }
    } 
    this.validate();
}   

private void tableCheckBoxActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int row = this.ordersTable.getSelectedRow();
    System.out.println(row);
    this.changeFlag = true;
}
```

**Relevant source code from data model:**

```
 public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    boolean ret = false;
    if( columnIndex == 0 ) {
        ret = true;             
    }
    return ret;
}

   public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object ret = " ";

    if( rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < getRowCount() ) {
        JobPlan obj = (JobPlan)modelData.get( rowIndex );
        switch( columnIndex ) {
            case 0: ret = obj.getGroupFlag();
            break; 
     }
  }

 public Object getObjectAt(int rowIndex) {

    Object obj = null;
    if( rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < getRowCount() ) {
          obj = modelData.get( rowIndex );
    }
    return obj;
}

public void setValueAt( Object obj, int row, int col ) {
    // get the object
    JobPlan o = (JobPlan) this.modelData.get( row );
    switch( col ) {
        case 0:
            o.setGroupFlag((Boolean) obj);
        break;
        default: ;
    }
}
```

Is it possible that assigning an actionEvent to each checkbox is causing the problem as my code may think one actionEvent is applied to all checkboxes?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you know that a table can by default [render `Boolean` as a check box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) by simply overriding `getColumnClass` in the table model?

Comment: I will try this. Does this eliminate the possibility to attach an actionListener to the checkbox however?

Comment: Also, when using `table.getSelectedRow`, we should generally convert that _view row_ to the actual _model row_ before performing operations on the row. Matters mostly for sorting and filtering, but its good to make a habit of it. See [convertRowIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-)

Comment: You don't need an `ActionListener`. `setValueAt` will be called when you check/uncheck it. So if you need to perform some operation on the model when check/unchecked, that's where you do it. If you need to operate on something outside the model, maybe a `TableModelListener` will work

Comment: Thanks for the help peeskillet. I tried your method and it seemed to fix my issue of having all of the check boxes being selected at once. However, it presented the issue of the table not displaying a combo box, but rather true/false. It did lead me to the solution using my original code. My persistence wasn't updated server-side to include the boolean flag which the check boxes represented. Rookie mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you override `getColumnClass`? And get rid of any renderers. The default renderer will render it to a check box

Comment: I ended up keeping the    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new FormatTableCellRenderer(); so that is possibly the cause of the issue I was having there.